# timetable for scheduled subjects

Tags: php, css, arrays

i got it right though my problem now is how can i put a style on the table row that has the data inside it and much better if i can put rowspan to it so that it will look like one table row.

here is the output:

[image]

and here is my code:

```html
<?php
 $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "bsu_db");
 if($db->connect_errno > 0){
     die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
 } 
 $times = ["7:00:00", "7:30:00", "8:00:00", "8:30:00", "9:00:00", "9:30:00", "10:00:00", "10:30:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "12:00:00"];
 $days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
 $SubjDay = array();
 $sqlSubjDay = "SELECT * FROM subject_day_tbl";
 $qrySubjDay = $db->query($sqlSubjDay);
 while($rowSubjDay = $qrySubjDay->fetch_assoc()){
  //array_push($SubjDay, $rowSubjDay['sub_day'], $rowSubjDay['start_time'], $rowSubjDay['end_time']);
  $SubjDay[] = $rowSubjDay;
 }
 json_encode($SubjDay);
?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <?php
    foreach ($days as $day ) {
     echo "<th>$day</th>";
    }
   ?>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php 
  foreach ($times as $time) {      
 ?>
 <tr> 
  <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
  <?php
   foreach ($days as $day) {           
    echo "<td>";
    foreach($SubjDay as $sd){
           
     if($day == $sd['sub_day'] && strtotime($time) >= strtotime($sd['start_time']) && strtotime($time) <= strtotime($sd['end_time'])){
      echo $sd['sub_day'] , " " , $sd['start_time'] , " - " , $sd['end_time'];
     }
           
    }
    echo "</td>";
   }

  ?>
 </tr>
 <?php   
  } 
 ?>     
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understandit. Can't you please attach an image with desired output? Or maybe explain a bit better. :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply because i was in the school,..i have updated my question now and also the codes,..based on the picture now i dont really understand why they pop out on the wrong table row (those table row which have underline).

Comment: i also tried to erase my if statement but same result :(

Comment: You shouldn't really run SQL statements in 2 foreach cycles. Run the SQL before to get all data that you need and iterate through that data in those cycles.

Comment: @MarthyM may i know how? im basing my statements on the time and day on the loop.

Comment: @MarthyM i updated my codes,..is this the correct way?? though the result still same :(

Comment: WTH i can't believe but i just get the right codes just now ha ha,..thank you so much for those who comments

Comment: Basically yes, this reduces the database calls. If you don't want all the data, use the [SQL where clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp).